# Camera2 Api showing white screen on camera only in android 28 pie device

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-9.0-pie

I am using **camera2 api** and it is working fine on **pre Pie android version** but it is showing white screen when opening camera on android pie devices. I have checked on emulator, A10 devices.
Kindly help me

app build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

I have also declared permissions

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" /> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Here is the logs:

```
2020-01-06 21:43:04.354 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:04.960 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1246ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=863946795696, Vsync=864596795670, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=864606099000, AnimationStart=864606243100, PerformTraversalsStart=864606749200, DrawStart=865124397700, SyncQueued=865125104600, SyncStart=865126372900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=865126580100, SwapBuffers=865128343100, FrameCompleted=865194693500, DequeueBufferDuration=135000, QueueBufferDuration=1984000, 
2020-01-06 21:43:04.995 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:05.037 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:05.094 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:05.229 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=853ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=864625292593, Vsync=865241959235, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=865246522400, AnimationStart=865246651100, PerformTraversalsStart=865257381400, DrawStart=865345430100, SyncQueued=865345513800, SyncStart=865347226700, IssueDrawCommandsStart=865347728400, SwapBuffers=865348734300, FrameCompleted=865480205200, DequeueBufferDuration=5031000, QueueBufferDuration=9624000, 
2020-01-06 21:43:05.256 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:08.829 4923-5340/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CConversion: Creating output document: /data/user/0/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture/cache/temp/output.pdf
2020-01-06 21:43:08.899 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:08.965 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xbbc70100 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xbfb7f490
2020-01-06 21:43:09.018 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:13.564 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:16.035 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:16.352 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.353 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.394 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.424 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/chatty: uid=10088(com.iris.idrs.smartcapture) identical 1 line
2020-01-06 21:43:16.425 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.474 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.602 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2020-01-06 21:43:16.878 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1553ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=875568052075, Vsync=876284718713, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=876287357500, AnimationStart=876287533900, PerformTraversalsStart=876287961000, DrawStart=876918332800, SyncQueued=876919028800, SyncStart=876926725800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=876946153900, SwapBuffers=876951883200, FrameCompleted=877129627800, DequeueBufferDuration=132000, QueueBufferDuration=1326000, 
2020-01-06 21:43:16.880 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:17.027 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:31.548 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/System: A resource failed to call destroy. 
2020-01-06 21:43:31.551 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/chatty: uid=10088(com.iris.idrs.smartcapture) FinalizerDaemon identical 7 lines
2020-01-06 21:43:31.552 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/System: A resource failed to call destroy. 
2020-01-06 21:43:42.533 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/ViewRootImpl[CConversionActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=902633, downTime=902633, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
2020-01-06 21:43:43.110 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:43.283 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1026ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=902505438851, Vsync=902772105507, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=902785072800, AnimationStart=902785162200, PerformTraversalsStart=902785352700, DrawStart=903355162800, SyncQueued=903361009100, SyncStart=903363119200, IssueDrawCommandsStart=903363531400, SwapBuffers=903370175800, FrameCompleted=903534179400, DequeueBufferDuration=64210000, QueueBufferDuration=23339000, 
2020-01-06 21:43:43.283 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:43.287 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/ViewRootImpl[CConversionActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=902692, downTime=902633, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
2020-01-06 21:43:43.793 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
2020-01-06 21:43:43.794 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:44.175 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:43.376 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/chatty: uid=10088(com.iris.idrs.smartcapture) identical 7 lines
2020-01-06 21:43:43.376 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/ViewRootImpl[CConversionActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=902692, downTime=902633, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
2020-01-06 21:43:47.715 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:48.918 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:49.436 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346907648 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:43:49.722 4923-4964/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/rs.smartcaptur: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2020(149KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/15MB, paused 1.459ms total 272.922ms
2020-01-06 21:43:49.772 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346907968 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:43:49.802 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346900368 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:43:49.888 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:50.151 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture E/CCaptureActivity: The camera encountered an error: 4
2020-01-06 21:43:50.198 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:50.266 4923-4964/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/rs.smartcaptur: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 5180(277KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 23MB/29MB, paused 1.626ms total 100.079ms
2020-01-06 21:43:52.168 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:43:52.961 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:53.167 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:43:54.084 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:44:04.197 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:44:08.168 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/System: A resource failed to call destroy. 
2020-01-06 21:44:08.172 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/chatty: uid=10088(com.iris.idrs.smartcapture) FinalizerDaemon identical 7 lines
2020-01-06 21:44:08.172 4923-4961/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture W/System: A resource failed to call destroy. 
2020-01-06 21:44:51.860 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=973ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=971138216354, Vsync=971588216336, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=971604458900, AnimationStart=971604599700, PerformTraversalsStart=971605101500, DrawStart=972056683900, SyncQueued=972057201200, SyncStart=972057276400, IssueDrawCommandsStart=972057444900, SwapBuffers=972059625400, FrameCompleted=972111965000, DequeueBufferDuration=621000, QueueBufferDuration=1859000, 
2020-01-06 21:44:51.861 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-06 21:44:51.951 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:44:51.998 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
2020-01-06 21:44:52.081 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=732ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=971597490482, Vsync=972097490462, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=972112842700, AnimationStart=972112945800, PerformTraversalsStart=972114580600, DrawStart=972248683500, SyncQueued=972248764000, SyncStart=972251096700, IssueDrawCommandsStart=972253391700, SwapBuffers=972254863000, FrameCompleted=972332311000, DequeueBufferDuration=136000, QueueBufferDuration=17695000, 
2020-01-06 21:44:52.081 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
I/CCaptureActivity: Capture size selected: 960 x 1280
2020-01-06 21:44:55.241 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346895328 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:44:55.286 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346899568 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:44:55.320 4923-4923/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/CCapture: Instance 3346553712 ==== Initialization complete
2020-01-06 21:44:55.846 4923-4964/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture I/rs.smartcaptur: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 66(54KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 23MB/29MB, paused 1.424ms total 473.768ms
2020-01-06 21:44:55.938 4923-5012/com.iris.idrs.smartcapture D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2ee8a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdee597c0)
```

I have also noticed sometimes it work only first time and then second time it shows white screen.
Here is the capture activity code

```
public class CCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  /**
   * Activity creation handler.
   * @param argSavedInstanceState Instance saved during previous session (unused).
   */
  @Override
  protected void onCreate ( final Bundle argSavedInstanceState )
  {
    super.onCreate ( argSavedInstanceState );
    // Fetch the UI elements which will be updated programatically during activity runtime.
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_capture );

    m_objDocumentAreaView = (CDocumentAreaView) findViewById ( R.id.corners_view );
    m_objCameraView = (CCameraView) findViewById ( R.id.camera_view );
    // Select the camera to use and initialize it as well as its preview and the needed handlers.
    m_objPreviewImageListener = new CCaptureAnalysisRunner ();
    setupCameraViewListener ();
    setupCameraStatusCallback ();
    m_objPreviewThread = new HandlerThread ( "PreviewUpdate" );
    m_objCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService ( Context.CAMERA_SERVICE );
    getCamera ();
    m_objHardwareStatus.onCreate ( this );
  }
  @Override
  protected void onResume ()
  {
    super.onResume ();

    m_objHardwareStatus.onResume ();
    m_objIdrsCapture.onResume ( this );
    openCamera ();
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPause ()
  {
    m_objIdrsCapture.onPause ();
    m_objHardwareStatus.onPause ();
    closeCamera ();
    super.onPause ();
  }

  private class CCaptureAnalysisRunner implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener
  {

    public void onImageAvailable ( final ImageReader argImageReader )
    {
      final Image objCapturedImage = argImageReader.acquireLatestImage ();
      // The image may be null sometimes, so skip processing in such case
      if ( null != objCapturedImage )
      {
        final boolean bDocumentExposureOk = m_objHardwareStatus.isExposureOk ();
        final boolean bCameraFocusSet = ( bDocumentExposureOk && m_objHardwareStatus.isFocusSet ());
        final boolean bDeviceStable = ( bCameraFocusSet && m_objHardwareStatus.isDeviceStable ());

        final CIdrsCapture.CWorker objWorker = (( bDeviceStable || m_bForceCapture ) ? m_objIdrsCapture.tryLock () : null );
        if ( objWorker != null )
        {
          Log.i ( "CCaptureActivity", "An image is available and will be processed" );

          objWorker.setCurrentCapture ( objCapturedImage );
          objCapturedImage.close ();

          AsyncTask.execute ( new Runnable ()
          {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
              onImageAnalysisCompleted ( objWorker, objWorker.detectDocumentCorners ());
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          objCapturedImage.close ();
        }
        // In any case, the indicators must be updated
        runOnUiThread ( new Runnable ()
        {
          @Override
          public void run ()
          {

            if ( m_objDocumentAreaView.reduceIntensity ())
            {
              m_objCornersFlag.setChecked ( false );
              m_objAreaFlag.setChecked ( false );
            }
            m_objExposureFlag.setChecked ( bDocumentExposureOk );
            m_objFocusFlag.setChecked ( bCameraFocusSet );
            m_objStabilityFlag.setChecked ( bDeviceStable );
            m_objDocumentAreaView.invalidate ();
            m_objExposureFlag.invalidate ();
            m_objFocusFlag.invalidate ();
            m_objStabilityFlag.invalidate ();
          }
        });
      }
    }
    private void onImageAnalysisCompleted (final CIdrsCapture.CWorker argWorker, final CIdrsCapture.DocumentCorners argDocumentCorners)
    {

      if ( ! m_objIdrsCapture.isCaptureSelected ())
      {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            m_objCornersFlag.setChecked(argDocumentCorners.bCornersFound);
            m_objAreaFlag.setChecked(argDocumentCorners.bTargetAreaOk);
            if (argDocumentCorners.bCornersFound)
            {
              m_objDocumentAreaView.setDetectedCorners(argDocumentCorners.xiCorners, argDocumentCorners.bTargetAreaOk);
            }
            m_objDocumentAreaView.invalidate();
            m_objCornersFlag.invalidate();
            m_objAreaFlag.invalidate();
          }
        });

        try
        {
          if (( argDocumentCorners.bCornersFound && argDocumentCorners.bTargetAreaOk ) || m_bForceCapture )
          {
     final int iCaptureQuality = m_bForceCapture ? 100 : argWorker.evaluateQuality ();

            boolean bCurrentCaptureSelected = false;
            boolean bCurrentCaptureForced = false;
            synchronized ( m_objCaptureSelectionLock )
            {
              if (iCaptureQuality >= CAPTURE_QUALITY_THRESHOLD && ! m_objIdrsCapture.isCaptureSelected ())
              {
                argWorker.selectCapture();
                bCurrentCaptureSelected = true;
                if ( m_bForceCapture )
                {
                  bCurrentCaptureForced = true;
                  m_bForceCapture = false;
                }
              }
            }
            // Update the controls only if no capture are currently selected or if this capture is the one selected
            final boolean bCurrentCaptureSelectedFinal = bCurrentCaptureSelected;
            final boolean bCurrentCaptureForcedFinal = bCurrentCaptureForced;
            if ( bCurrentCaptureSelected || ! m_objIdrsCapture.isCaptureSelected ())
            {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
              {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                  if ( ! bCurrentCaptureForcedFinal )
                  {
                    m_objImageQualityBar.setProgress(iCaptureQuality);
                  }
                  if ( bCurrentCaptureSelectedFinal )
                  {
                    m_objDocumentAreaView.setCaptureValidated();
                  }
                  m_objImageQualityBar.invalidate();
                  m_objCameraView.invalidate();
                }
              });

              if ( bCurrentCaptureSelected )
              {

                final String strSelectedImagePath = CPathProvider.getInternalPathSelectedImage ();
                argWorker.saveSelectedCapture ( strSelectedImagePath );

                final Intent objCaptureCorrectionIntent = new Intent ( CCaptureActivity.this, CAdjustmentActivity.class );
                objCaptureCorrectionIntent.putExtra ( "EXTRA_CAPTURED_IMAGE", strSelectedImagePath );
                if ( argDocumentCorners.bCornersFound )
                {
                  objCaptureCorrectionIntent.putExtra ( "EXTRA_DETECTED_CORNERS", argDocumentCorners.xiCorners );
                }
                CCaptureActivity.this.startActivity ( objCaptureCorrectionIntent );
              }
            }
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          // Unlock the worker before exiting
          argWorker.unlock ();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Setup the listener class that links the view to the camera.
   */
  private void setupCameraViewListener ()
  {
    m_objCameraView.setSurfaceTextureListener ( new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener ()
    {
      /**
       * Surface texture available handler.
       * @param argSurfaceTexture The surface texture (unused)
       * @param iWidth Surface texture width (unused)
       * @param iHeight Surface texture height (unused)
       */
      @Override
      public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable ( final SurfaceTexture argSurfaceTexture, final int iWidth, final int iHeight )
      {
        // No need to use the provided parameters - simply open the camera.
        openCamera ();
      }

      @Override
      public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged ( final SurfaceTexture argSurfaceTexture, final int iWidth, final int iHeight )
      {

      }

      @Override
      public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed ( final SurfaceTexture argSurfaceTexture )
      {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated ( final SurfaceTexture argSurfaceTexture )
      {

      }
    });
  }
  /**
   * Setup the camera status callback listener.
   */
  private void setupCameraStatusCallback ()
  {
    m_objCameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback ()
    {
      /**
       * Camera open handler.
       * @param argCameraDevice The camera opened.
       */
      @Override
      public void onOpened ( final CameraDevice argCameraDevice )
      {
        m_objCameraDevice = argCameraDevice;
        startCamera ();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDisconnected ( final CameraDevice argCameraDevice )
      {
      }

      @Override
      public void onError ( final CameraDevice argCameraDevice, final int iError )
      {
        if ( m_objCameraDevice != null && m_objCameraDevice.getId ().equals ( argCameraDevice.getId ()))
        {
          Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "The camera encountered an error: " + iError );
        }
      }
    };
  }

  private void getCamera ()
  {
    try
    {
      // Parse all available cameras and select the first rear-facing found.
      m_strCameraId = null;
      CameraCharacteristics objCameraCharacteristics = null;
      final String[] xstrCameraIds = m_objCameraManager.getCameraIdList ();
      for ( final String strCurrentCameraId : xstrCameraIds )
      {
        objCameraCharacteristics = m_objCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics ( strCurrentCameraId );
        if ( objCameraCharacteristics.get ( CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING ) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK )
        {
          m_strCameraId = strCurrentCameraId;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (m_strCameraId == null)
      {
        Log.e("CCaptureActivity", "Could not find device back camera");
      }

      final StreamConfigurationMap objStreamConfigurationMap = objCameraCharacteristics.get ( CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP );
      m_iCameraOrientation = objCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
      // Finally, retrieve the capture and preview sizes.
      m_objCaptureSize = selectCaptureSize ( objStreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes ( ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 ), m_iCameraOrientation );
      m_objPreviewSize = selectPreviewSize ( objStreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes ( SurfaceTexture.class ), m_objCaptureSize );
      Log.i ("CCaptureActivity", "Capture size selected: " + m_objCaptureSize.getHeight () + " x " + m_objCaptureSize.getWidth ());
      m_objIdrsCapture.setCharacteristics ( m_objCaptureSize, m_iCameraOrientation );
    }
    catch ( final Exception argException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "An exception occurred while retrieving the device camera", argException );
    }
  }

  private void openCamera ()
  {
    try
    {
      // Start or restart the preview handler if needed
      if ( ! m_objPreviewThread.isAlive() || m_objPreviewThread.isInterrupted ())
      {
        m_objPreviewThread.start();
      }
      m_objPreviewThreadHandler = new Handler ( m_objPreviewThread.getLooper ());
      m_objImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance ( m_objCaptureSize.getWidth (), m_objCaptureSize.getHeight (), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2 );
      m_objImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener ( m_objPreviewImageListener, m_objPreviewThreadHandler );

      m_objDocumentAreaView.setCaptureSize ( m_objCaptureSize, m_iCameraOrientation );
      m_objCameraView.setCaptureSize ( m_objCaptureSize );
      m_objCameraManager.openCamera ( m_strCameraId, m_objCameraStateCallback,null );
      m_bCameraOpen = true;
    }
    catch ( final SecurityException argSecurityException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "A security exception occurred while opening the device camera", argSecurityException );
    }
    catch (final Exception argException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "An exception occurred while opening the device camera", argException );
    }
  }

  private void startCamera ()
  {

    if ( m_objCameraDevice == null || ! m_objCameraView.isAvailable () || m_objPreviewSize == null )
    {
      return;
    }
    final SurfaceTexture argSurfaceTexture = m_objCameraView.getSurfaceTexture ();
    if ( argSurfaceTexture == null )
    {
      return;
    }

    argSurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize ( m_objPreviewSize.getWidth (), m_objPreviewSize.getHeight ());
    final Surface argSurface = new Surface ( argSurfaceTexture );
    try
    {
      m_objCaptureRequestBuilder = m_objCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest ( CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW );
    }
    catch ( final Exception argException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "An exception occurred when creating the capture request", argException );
    }
    m_objCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget ( argSurface );
    m_objCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget ( m_objImageReader.getSurface ());

    try
    {
      m_objCameraDevice.createCaptureSession ( Arrays.asList ( argSurface, m_objImageReader.getSurface ()),
        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback ()
        {

          @Override
          public void onConfigured ( final CameraCaptureSession argCameraCaptureSession )
          {
            m_objCameraCaptureSession = argCameraCaptureSession;
            onCaptureSessionConfigured ();
          }

          @Override
          public void onConfigureFailed ( final CameraCaptureSession argCameraCaptureSession )
          {
            Log.e ("CCaptureActivity", "The camera capture session could not be successfully created." );
          }
        },
        null );
    }
    catch ( final Exception argException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "An exception occurred when creating the capture session", argException );
    }
  }
  /**
   * Callback that will start capture session once it is configured.
   */
  private void onCaptureSessionConfigured ()
  {
    if ( m_objCameraDevice == null )
    {
      return;
    }
    m_objCaptureRequestBuilder.set ( CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO );
    try
    {
      m_objCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest ( m_objCaptureRequestBuilder.build (),
        m_objHardwareStatus,
        m_objPreviewThreadHandler );
    }
    catch ( final Exception argException )
    {
      Log.e ( "CCaptureActivity", "An exception occured while starting capture session", argException );
    }
  }
  private void closeCamera ()
  {
    if ( m_bCameraOpen )
    {
      m_objCameraDevice.close ();
      m_bCameraOpen = false;
    }
    if( m_objCameraCaptureSession != null )
    {
      m_objCameraCaptureSession.close();
    }
  }

  private Size selectCaptureSize ( final Size [] xargSizes, final int iCameraOrientation )
  {
    // Retrieve the screen dimensions to know its aspect ratio
    final DisplayMetrics objDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay ().getMetrics ( objDisplayMetrics );
    final float fScreenRatio = (float) objDisplayMetrics.widthPixels / objDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
    Size objMaxSizeSameRatio = null;
    Size objMaxSizeAnyRatio = null;
    // Now iterates on the list to find the largest (in area) below the accepted limit
    for (final Size objCurrent : xargSizes )
    {
      final int iAreaSize = objCurrent.getHeight () * objCurrent.getWidth ();
      final float fSizeRatio;
      if ( iCameraOrientation == 0 || iCameraOrientation == 180)
      {
        fSizeRatio = (float) objCurrent.getWidth () / objCurrent.getHeight ();
      }
      else
      {
        fSizeRatio = (float) objCurrent.getHeight () / objCurrent.getWidth ();
      }
      if ( iAreaSize < CAPTURE_SIZE_MAX_PIXELS )
      {
        // Search with same ratio
        if ( fSizeRatio == fScreenRatio &&
          ( objMaxSizeSameRatio == null || ( objMaxSizeSameRatio.getWidth () * objMaxSizeSameRatio.getHeight () < iAreaSize )))
        {
          objMaxSizeSameRatio = objCurrent;
        }
        // Search as well without taking the ratio into account
        if ( objMaxSizeAnyRatio == null || ( objMaxSizeAnyRatio.getWidth () * objMaxSizeAnyRatio.getHeight () < iAreaSize ))
        {
          objMaxSizeAnyRatio = objCurrent;
        }
      }
    }
    return objMaxSizeSameRatio != null ? objMaxSizeSameRatio : objMaxSizeAnyRatio;
  }
```

Comment: Please add logcat from when you try to run your app.  There's not enough information here to debug what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was on leaves. But problem is still there. Kindly check logs

Comment: Did you find any solution. Im also facing same issue. Im using cameraX for image analysis but only first time it runs then showing white screen. Kindly share solution if you resolve this.

Comment: @Muhammad no brother still stuck in this issue.

Comment: Your logcat only covers your own app's logging - try to capture the full-system logcat to show what the camera API and hardware is doing.  That may help see where the startup is getting stuck.  

One possible issue is that you're calling openCamera from both onSurfaceTextureAvailable and from onResume, which could cause it to run twice and confuse things.  Second, I don't see any handling of requesting the camera permission, though maybe that's in another activity.

Comment: Thanks @EddyTalvala. I will add more logs but my app is working fine on android oreo, marshmallow etc

Comment: @EddyTalvala I have already covered permission in starting activity. That is not issue but thanks for identification.

Comment: @EddyTalvala I checked by commenting onResume code but still problem exists